# Merge two integers as integer.decimal in C

Tags: c, function, merge

I have 2 integers and I want to merge these two numbers as integer.decimal . For example:

```
int a = 12;
int b = 54367;

double c = aFunction(a,b);
```

then I want

> c = 12.54367

How can I make this in C? Is there any specific "aFunction" in standard C Library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is anything that merges two integers, but with `log10` and `pow` from `math.h`, it is easy!

```
double aFunction(int a, int b)
{
    int decimals = log10(b) + 1;
    return a + b*pow(10.0, -decimals);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the second argument to the function has to be an `unsigned` type. It doesn't make sense for it to be a `signed` type. Given that, the following function works for me.

```
double aFunction(int a, unsigned int b)
{
   unsigned int b1 = b%10;
   unsigned int b2 = b/10;
   double dec = 0.0;
   while ( b2 > 0 )
   {
      dec = (dec + b1)/10.0;
      b1 = b2%10;
      b2 = b2/10;
   }
   dec = (dec + b1)/10.0;
   return a + dec;
}
```

See working code at http://ideone.com/GoBUcB.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post this and then **myurtoglu** did, if it's the right answer pick his answer, I will post mine because I think you can understand my function better.

```
double merge(int integerPart, int decimalPart)
{
    double result;
    int    exponent;

    result   = (double)integerPart;
    exponent = (int)log10(decimalPart);
    result  += (double)decimalPart / pow(10.0, 1 + exponent);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses `unsigned` integers as the problem statement is not clear when they are signed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double aFunction (unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    double d = (double)b;
    while (d >= 1) 
        d /= 10;
    return (double)a + d;
}

int main()  {
    int a = 12;
    int b = 54367;
    double c = aFunction(a,b);
    printf("%f\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```